# Simple PyQt4 showing other windows

Tags: python, user-interface, widget, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to make a simple widget with three buttons where for each button when clicked will show the corresponding other widgets.

Following is the code I'm trying to run but cant figure out why the new widgets are not showing.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from functools import partial
import sys


class MainWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
       super(MainWidget, self).__init__()

       self.main_widget()

    def main_widget(self):
        another = Another()
        simple = Simple()
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()

        show_another_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Show Another")
        show_another_button.clicked.connect(another.show_another)
        grid.addWidget(show_another_button, 0, 0)

        show_simple_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Show Simple")
        show_simple_button.clicked.connect(simple.show_simple)
        grid.addWidget(show_simple_button, 0, 1)

        print_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Print Hello")
        print_button.clicked.connect(partial(print, "Hello"))
        grid.addWidget(another_button, 0, 2)

        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.show()


class Another(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        print("another initialized")
        super(Another, self).__init__()

    def show_another(self):
        print("another called")
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()

        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.show()


class Simple(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        print("simple initialized")
        super(Simple, self).__init__()

    def show_simple(self):
        print("simple called")
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_widget = MainWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Please Help!

Comment: They probably got garbage collected at the end of the function. Try making them instance attributes. Changing `simple` to `self.simple` and the same for another. Also another don't have a function `show_another` and `ex = Example()` is probably a typo.

Comment: Yea actually kinda figured that out and yes Example is a typo and fixed it too. Thanx for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified your code slightly. The below works on my system.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from functools import partial
import sys


class MainWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__()

        self.another = Another()
        self.simple = Simple()
        self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()

        self.main_widget()

    def main_widget(self):
        show_another_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Show Another")
        show_another_button.clicked.connect(self.another.show_form)
        self.grid.addWidget(show_another_button, 0, 0)

        show_simple_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Show Simple")
        show_simple_button.clicked.connect(self.simple.show_simple)
        self.grid.addWidget(show_simple_button, 0, 1)

        another_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Print Hello")
        another_button.clicked.connect(partial(print, "Hello"))
        self.grid.addWidget(another_button, 0, 2)

        self.setLayout(self.grid)


class Another(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Another, self).__init__()
        print("another initialized")

    def show_form(self):
        print("another called")
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()

        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.show()


class Simple(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Simple, self).__init__()
        print("simple initialized")

    def show_simple(self):
        print("simple called")
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Please note: If you try to launch Another() when the Widget is still open you will get an error:

QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on Another "", which already has a layout

Comment: So how will I go about if I want to open a new window while the first one is already open???

Comment: I would move the code setting the grid layout in the Another() class to the init function (this will stop the error as __init__ is only run when object is initialised). Then from where you want to call another just initialise it with a new name for example self.another_2 = Another()

Alternatively you could make an array of classes and just add and remove them as you need them.